# Should I do git merge directly from dev to stg?

Tags: git, gitlab

I am learning git these days. We have a 3 branches like dev, stg, prod. So the process goes like `dev -> stg -> prod`. BTW, ours is a small project, so we do not have anything like features/versions branches etc.

**My query is**: After I pushed to 'dev', Now should I directly merge from 'dev' to 'stg' orelse how exactly you do?(assume I fixed one bug, so it should get reflected in prod too) I knew this is a dumb query, but I am practicing.

And also will you merge directly from stg to prod directly?

Comment: What is the point of the `dev`, `stg`, and `prod` branches?  Seems as though you're treating your vcs as though it's a development environment.

Comment: @ThomasStringer Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: @John, @Thomas is asking why you have a `stg` branch, because it's not clear why you'd have one in source control. It makes sense to have a staging environment where you might test potential releases, but it's unclear why you need a separate branch in source control for that.

Comment: `staging` is interesting nomenclature for a branch.  I can understand the `dev` branches, and the "prod" branches (typically `master`).  What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @ThomasStringer This structure already created for our project. not sure exactly why. Why dont you please answer my query?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Gitflow workflow. If is it you should never go from dev -> stg -> prod directly.

To merge your commits from one branch to another you should work with features and releases.

Take a look at this [documentation](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow/) from Atlassian.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that this can go from dev->-stage only if it's in real initial stages of project because you don't have much to test anyway. If it's just the basic framework and passes unit tests,sure why not. But again, that's my personal opinion.